# A2I integration to asynchronous textract call

Tags: amazon-textract

i have seen that A2I Human Loop invocation is still not available with the asynchronous API calls of aws textract. Is there any chance to start a human loop after textract stored its result in a S3 bucket, for example with a A2I custom task type?